# Edge closes automatically at the end of macro

Tags: selenium, browser

While automating edge browser using selenium vba, the edge browser automatically closes when the macro end sub function is executed. Is there a way to control this action & edge does not close automatically?

Answer (score 0):

So, to avoid quitting the browser, you need to set the instance of the driver on a global variable:

```
Private Assert As New Assert
Private driver As New Selenium.FirefoxDriver

Sub ProcMain()
    driver.Get "http://stackoverflow.com"
    Call ClickLogo
End Sub

Sub QuitDriver()
    driver.Quit
End Sub

Sub ClickLogo()
    driver.FindElementByCss("#hlogo").Click
End Sub
```

***Or For Example for Edge***

```
Dim driver as WebDriver

Sub Repsol()

Set driver = New EdgeDriver
With driver

.Start "edge"
.Get "https://login.repsol.com/es/Landing/AuthnPage?returnUrl=https://www.repsol.com/es_es/"

 With .FindElementByClass("gigya-login-form")

        .FindElementByClass("gigya-input-text").SendKeys "user" 'your user
        .FindElementByClass("gigya-input-password").SendKeys "password" 'your password
         
         
         .FindElementByClass("gigya-input-submit").submit
End With

 Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
 .Get "https://www.repsol.com/es_es/aplicaciones/SO/WebEESS/default.aspx?usuario="""
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)

         
 .Get "https://www.repsol.com/SO/WebEESS/Pages/Carburantes/PeticionCarburante/Peticion.aspx"

 With .FindElementByClass("tablaContenedora")

        .FindElementById("ctl00_zona1_grdwCarburantes_ctl02_lbltxtCantidad").SendKeys [B7]

         End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Neelam, Please accept the answer if your issue is resolved.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. But making the driver variable as global did not solve my issue